# How to turn off file and folder refactoring in netbeans 6.9 or 7.0 beta 2

Tags: php, netbeans, refactoring

I want to turn off annoying file refactoring as I have a php project and it is useless

If i click a folder and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename that folder, it won't let me do it without going through the refactoring dialogue, which is buggy so that makes it worse.

For example when I hit "do not refactor" checkbox, the affirmative action button says "preview"... what does that even mean?

And then to make matters worse, sometimes it refuses to rename a file or folder and I can't work out why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Renaming files with F2 works for me in 6.9.1 without saying anything about refactoring. Changing extension is a little tricky though (must be done via right click -> properties).

Comment: About the "Preview" button - it is for previewing changes that are to be done, when refactoring. In 6.9.1, I see either only "OK", if *rename without refactoring* checkbox was checked when dialog window was opened, or "Preview" and "Refactor", if checkbox was unchecked.

Comment: I'm using 7.0 beta 2 on windows 7. I had the same problem in 6.9. It never says okay for me, always says preview. rename without refactoring checkbox is checked

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>F2</kbd> in "Projects" browser works for me in NetBeans 7.

- Open "Tools/Options/Keymap"
- press <kbd>F2</kbd> in "Search in Shortcuts"
- make sure that <kbd>F2</kbd> is not assigned to "Refactor"

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> that set by default. You can go to tool->options->keymaps then search for rename and change to the shortcut accordingly.

Comment: There's no shortcut item to do rename, it's only refactor... damn you netbeans 7.0 rc2

Answer (score 0):

Unbind shortkeys ?

Comment: but when i try to move a folder it still would attempt to do the refactor. This is if i drag and drop it

Answer (score -1):

Rename the folder outside netbeans?!

Comment: Not quite a solution for a problem, and needs some file manager (e.g., very unhandy *windows explorer*) to be involved.